# Vaadin Flow grid add an empty row

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

How can someone add a new empty line (perhaps at the bottom or at the top of the grid) programmatically.
At a later state the user enters data, or after some actions save all the rows perhaps in the database.

Comment: Vague question. I don’t see the connection between your two sentences. Also, the use of “perhaps” repeatedly is confusing. Please put more effort into drafting a detailed clear Question *before* posting.

Comment: You might want to explain why you want an extra blank row as there may be a better way to accomplish whatever is your real goal.

Comment: I need an extra editable row so the user can type data in each cell. After adding multiple lines the user can save in db, but this happens latter.

Answer (score 2):

Technically it should be rather simple, especially if you use `ListDataProvider` for the Grid, here simplified example:

```
Grid<Bean> grid = new Grid<>(Bean.class);
ListDataProvider<Bean> dp = new ListDataProvider<>(getData());
grid.setDataProvider(dp);
add(grid);

Button button = new Button("Add row");
button.addClickListener(event -> {
    Bean bean = new Bean();
    dp.getItems().add(bean);
    dp.refreshAll();
    grid.getEditor().editItem(bean);       
});
add(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You using ListDataProvider set fof dataprovider of grid.
2. Bean object Override hashCode method.
   for Example :

   @Transient
   private long sId;

   public ConstructorMethod () {
   sId = System.currentTimeMillis();
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
   if (isNew())
   return (int) (super.hashCode()+sId);
   else
   return super.hashCode();
   }
3. New a bean object and add to ListDataProvider of grid

   ```
    BeanClass item = new BeanClass();
   (ListDataProvider<BeanClass>)grid.getDataProvider().getItems().add(item);
   (ListDataProvider<BeanClass>)grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
   ```